# Need suggestion to upgrade WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final

Tags: wildfly

I need help to upgrade WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final.
Which version is best to upgrade wildfly.
I have done some research but not workout. can anyone help me out for this.?

Currently we are using JBoss Modules version 1.6.1.Final
WildFly Full 11.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final).

any suggestions please.

Comment: Latest Wildfly version is 26.1.2 It is the latest version supporting Java8 and Jakartaee 8.

Comment: What happens when you deploy your current application to the newer server?